# Телеграм бот может удалить свои сообщения?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Я хочу удалить все сообщения бота, которые бот отправил пользователю в их личной переписке. Это возможно сделать?
Сообщения самого пользователя уже не важно останутся или нет. Главное удалить сообщения самого бота.

Comment: У объекта `message` вызвать метод `delete`: https://github.com/gil9red/telegram_bot__gamebook/blob/309b98a93bc1a15b25ad5b32e0a1f4b772e6687d/bot/commands.py#L282

Comment: Меня интересует удалить вообще все сообщения которые были отправлены ботом. Это возможно?

Comment: Храните id сообщений и чатов в базе данных (или в файле), после вызывайте тот метод у бота: `delete_message(self, chat_id, message_id, ...`: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/eace25d9d254430b18d3635ca66584275a79ce3f/telebot/__init__.py#L778

Answer (score 1):

Да, может, вот официальная документация по методу deleteMessage:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage